# Compile error: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, dynamic-linking, relocation

I try to make functions in assembly language and put them in a dynamic library so I create .o with .S with this command:
    `nasm -f elf64 hello.S -o hello.o`
but when I want to create the lib with gcc:
    `gcc -fPIC -shared hello.o -o libasm.so`
and it displays me this error:
   `/usr/bin/ld: hello.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5 can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Comment: See http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10rc8/html/nasmdoc9.html#section-9.2.5 (_Calling procedures outside the library_)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.10rc8/html/nasmdoc9.html#section-9.2.5:

> To call an external routine, you must use another special PIC relocation type, WRT ..plt. This is much easier than the GOT-based ones: you simply replace calls such as CALL printf with the PLT-relative version CALL printf WRT ..plt.

so instead of

```
; ...
call     printf
```

use

```
; ...
call     printf WRT ..plt
```

and compile and link as normal.

BTW, "WRT" means "With Respect To ...", i.e, "in the context of ..."

Comment: Or better, `call [rel printf wrt ..got]` like `gcc -fno-plt` uses.  Full details in [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52126328)

Comment: maybe this should be closed as duplicate of that if the justification for `..got` appears there?

Comment: I already did close it as a duplicate, right after updating my answer on the linked question to include a TL:DR at the top :P  And yes, my answer there describes the fact that using the GOT pointer directly removes the layer of indirection through the PLT.

Comment: ah, way ahead of me