# Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, yasm

I have a function `foo` written in assembly and compiled with yasm and GCC on Linux (Ubuntu) 64-bit. It simply prints a message to stdout using `puts()`, here is how it looks:

```
bits 64

extern puts
global foo

section .data

message:
  db 'foo() called', 0

section .text

foo:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  lea rdi, [rel message]
  call puts
  pop rbp
  ret
```

It is called by a C program compiled with GCC:

```
extern void foo();

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Build commands:

```
yasm -f elf64 foo_64_unix.asm
gcc -c foo_main.c -o foo_main.o
gcc foo_64_unix.o foo_main.o -o foo
./foo
```

Here is the problem:

When running the program it prints an error message and immediately segfaults during the call to `puts`:

```
./foo: Symbol `puts' causes overflow in R_X86_64_PC32 relocation
Segmentation fault
```

After disassembling with objdump I see that the call is made with the wrong address:

```
0000000000000660 <foo>:
 660:   90                      nop
 661:   55                      push   %rbp
 662:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 665:   48 8d 3d a4 09 20 00    lea    0x2009a4(%rip),%rdi
 66c:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  671 <foo+0x11>      <-- here
 671:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 672:   c3                      retq
```

(671 is the address of the next instruction, not address of `puts`)

However, if I rewrite the same code in C the call is done differently:

```
645:   e8 c6 fe ff ff          callq  510 <puts@plt>
```

i.e. it references `puts` from the PLT.

Is it possible to tell yasm to generate similar code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `0xe8` opcode is followed by a signed offset to be applied to the PC (which has advanced to the next instruction by that time) to compute the branch target.  Hence `objdump` is interpreting the branch target as `0x671`.

YASM is rendering zeros because it has likely put a relocation on that offset, which is how it asks the loader to populate the correct offset for `puts` during loading. The loader is encountering an overflow when computing the relocation, which may indicate that `puts` is at a further offset from your call than can be represented in a 32-bit signed offset. Hence the loader fails to fix this instruction, and you get a crash.

`66c: e8 00 00 00 00` shows the unpopulated address. If you look in your relocation table, you should see a relocation on `0x66d`. It is not uncommon for the assembler to populate addresses/offsets with relocations as all zeros.

[This page](https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/objfmt-elf64.html) suggests that YASM has a `WRT` directive that can control use of `.got`, `.plt`, etc.

Per S9.2.5 on [the NASM documentation](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc9.html), it looks like you can use `CALL puts WRT ..plt` (presuming YASM has the same syntax).

Answer (score 24):

TL:DR: 3 options:

- Build a non-PIE executable (`gcc -no-pie -fno-pie  call-lib.c libcall.o`) so the linker will generate a PLT entry for you transparently when you write `call puts`.
- `call puts wrt ..plt`  like `gcc -fPIE` would do.
- **`call [rel puts wrt ..got]` like `gcc -fno-plt` would do.**

The latter two will work in PIE executables or shared libraries.  The 3rd way, `wrt ..got`, is slightly more efficient.

---

Your gcc is building PIE executables by default ([32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)).

I'm not sure why, but when doing so the linker doesn't automatically resolve `call puts` to `call puts@plt`.  There is still a `puts` PLT entry generated, but the `call` doesn't go there.

At runtime, the dynamic linker tries to resolve `puts` directly to the libc symbol of that name and fixup the `call rel32`.  But the symbol is more than +-2^31 away, so we get a warning about overflow of the `R_X86_64_PC32` relocation.  The low 32 bits of the target address are correct, but the upper bits aren't.  (Thus your `call` jumps to a bad address).

---

**Your code works for me if I build with `gcc -no-pie -fno-pie  call-lib.c libcall.o`**.  The `-no-pie` is the critical part: it's the linker option.  Your YASM command doesn't have to change.

When making a traditional position-dependent executable, the linker turns the `puts` symbol for the call target into `puts@plt` for you, because we're linking a dynamic executable (instead of statically linking libc with `gcc -static -fno-pie`, in which case the `call` could go *directly* to the libc function.)

Anyway, this is why gcc emits `call puts@plt` (GAS syntax) when compiling with `-fpie` (the default on your desktop, but not the default on https://godbolt.org/), but just `call puts` when compiling with `-fno-pie`.

---

See [What does @plt mean here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469274/what-does-plt-mean-here) for more about the PLT, and also [Sorry state of dynamic libraries on Linux](https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/) from a few years ago.  (The modern `gcc -fno-plt` is like one of the ideas in that blog post.)

---

BTW, a more accurate/specific prototype would let gcc avoid zeroing EAX before calling `foo`:

`extern void foo();` in C means `extern void foo(...);`
You could declare it as `extern void foo(void);`, which is what `()` means in C++.  C++ doesn't allow function declarations that leave the args unspecified.

---

**asm improvements**

You can also put `message` in `section .rodata` (read-only data, linked as part of the text segment).

You don't need a stack frame, just something to align the stack by 16 before a call.  A dummy `push  rax` will do it.

Or we can tail-call `puts` by *jumping* to it instead of calling it, with the same stack position as on entry to this function.  This works with or without PIE.  Just replace `call` with `jmp`, as long as RSP is pointing at your own return address.

### If you want to make PIE executables (or shared libraries), you have two options

- `call puts wrt ..plt` - explicitly call through the PLT.
- **`call [rel puts wrt ..got]`** - explicitly do an indirect call through the GOT entry, like gcc's `-fno-plt` style of code-gen.  (Using a RIP-relative addressing mode to reach the GOT, hence the `rel` keyword).

WRT = With Respect To.  The NASM manual [documents `wrt ..plt`](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc9.html#section-9.2.5), and see also [section 7.9.3: special symbols and WRT](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.3).

Normally you would use `default rel` at the top of your file so you can actually use `call [puts wrt ..got]` and still get a RIP-relative addressing mode.  You can't use a 32-bit absolute addressing mode in PIE or PIC code.

`call [puts wrt ..got]` assembles to a memory-indirect call using the function pointer that dynamic linking stored in the GOT.  (Early-binding, not lazy dynamic linking.)

NASM documents `..got` for getting the address of variables in [section 9.2.3](https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc9.html#section-9.2.3).  Functions in (other) libraries are identical: you get a pointer from the GOT instead of calling directly, because the offset isn't a link-time constant and might not fit in 32-bits.

YASM also accepts `call [puts wrt ..GOTPCREL]`, like AT&T syntax `call *puts@GOTPCREL(%rip)`, but NASM does not.

```
; don't use BITS 64.  You *want* an error if you try to assemble this into a 32-bit .o

default rel          ; RIP-relative addressing instead of 32-bit absolute by default; makes the [rel ...] optional

section .rodata            ; .rodata is best for constants, not .data
message:
  db 'foo() called', 0

section .text

global foo
foo:
    sub    rsp, 8                ; align the stack by 16

    ; PIE with PLT
    lea    rdi, [rel message]      ; needed for PIE
    call   puts WRT ..plt          ; tailcall puts
;or
    ; PIE with -fno-plt style code, skips the PLT indirection
    lea   rdi, [rel message]
    call  [rel  puts wrt ..got]
;or
    ; non-PIE
    mov    edi, message           ; more efficient, but only works in non-PIE / non-PIC
    call   puts                   ; linker will rewrite it into call puts@plt

    add   rsp,8                   ; restore the stack, undoing the add
    ret
```

In a position-*dependent* Linux executable, you can use `mov edi, message` instead of a RIP-relative LEA.  It's smaller code-size and can run on more execution ports on most CPUs.  (Fun fact: MacOS always puts the "image base" outside the low 4GiB so this optimization isn't possible there.)

In a non-PIE executable, you also might as well use `call puts` or `jmp puts` and let the linker sort it out, unless you want more efficient no-plt style dynamic linking.  But if you do choose to statically link libc, I think this is the only way you'll get a direct jmp to the libc function.

(I think the possibility of static linking for non-PIE is *why* `ld` is willing to generate PLT stubs automatically for non-PIE, but not for PIE or shared libraries.  It requires you to say what you mean when linking ELF shared objects.)

If you did use `call puts` in a PIE (`call rel32`), it could only work if you statically linked a position-independent implementation of `puts` into your PIE, so the entire thing was one executable that would get loaded at a random address at runtime (by the usual dynamic-linker mechanism), but simply didn't have a dependency on `libc.so.6`

---

### Linker "relaxing" calls when the target is present at static-link time

GAS `call  *bar@GOTPCREL(%rip)` uses `R_X86_64_GOTPCRELX` (relaxable)
NASM `call [rel bar wrt ..got]` uses `R_X86_64_GOTPCREL` (not relaxable)

This is less of a problem with hand-written asm; you can just use `call bar` when you know the symbol will be present in another `.o` (rather than `.so`) that you're going to link.  But C compilers don't know the difference between library functions and other user functions you declare with prototypes (unless you use stuff like `gcc -fvisibility=hidden` https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility or attributes / pragmas).

Still, you might want to write asm source that the linker can optimize if you statically link a library, but AFAIK you can't do that with NASM.  You can export a symbol as hidden (visible at static-link time, but not for dynamic linking in the final .so) with `global  bar:function hidden`, but that's in the source file defining the function, not files accessing it.

---

```
global bar
bar:
    mov eax,231
    syscall
```

```
    call bar wrt ..plt
    call [rel bar wrt ..got]
extern bar
```

The 2nd file, after assembling with `nasm -felf64` and disassembling with `objdump -drwc -Mintel` to see the relocations:

```
0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   0x5      1: R_X86_64_PLT32       bar-0x4
   5:   ff 15 00 00 00 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # 0xb 7: R_X86_64_GOTPCREL    bar-0x4
```

After linking with `ld` (GNU Binutils) 2.35.1 - `ld bar.o bar2.o -o bar`

```
0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:       e8 0b 00 00 00          call   401010 <bar>
  401005:       ff 15 ed 1f 00 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x1fed]        # 402ff8 <.got>
  40100b:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]

0000000000401010 <bar>:
  401010:       b8 e7 00 00 00          mov    eax,0xe7
  401015:       0f 05                   syscall
```

Note that the PLT form got relaxed to just a direct `call bar`, PLT eliminated.  But the `ff 15` call [rel mem] was *not* relaxed to an `e8 rel32`

**With GAS:**

```
_start:
        call    bar@plt
        call    *bar@GOTPCREL(%rip)
```

`gcc -c foo.s && disas foo.o`

```
0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   5 <_start+0x5>   1: R_X86_64_PLT32       bar-0x4
   5:   ff 15 00 00 00 00       call   QWORD PTR [rip+0x0]        # b <_start+0xb>      7: R_X86_64_GOTPCRELX   bar-0x4
```

Note the X at the end of R_X86_64_GOTPCRELX.
`ld bar2.o foo.o -o bar && disas bar`:

```
0000000000401000 <bar>:
  401000:       b8 e7 00 00 00          mov    eax,0xe7
  401005:       0f 05                   syscall 

0000000000401007 <_start>:
  401007:       e8 f4 ff ff ff          call   401000 <bar>
  40100c:       67 e8 ee ff ff ff       addr32 call 401000 <bar>
```

Both calls got relaxed to a direct `e8` `call rel32` straight to the target address.  The extra byte in indirect call is filled with a `67` address-size prefix (which has no effect on `call rel32`), padding the instruction to the same length.  (Because it's too late to re-assemble and re-compute all relative branches within functions, and alignment and so on.)

That would happen for `call *puts@GOTPCREL(%rip)` if you statically linked libc, with `gcc -static`.

Comment: Related: examples of Hello World from `_start` and `main`: [Linking a program using printf with ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55315078)