# How can I call printf normally in assembly without @PLT but just call printf with -l option in gcc with standard library,

Tags: matplotlib, gcc, assembly, x86-64, linker-errors

I want to call printf in assembly and link it using gcc -l option with standard library, But it says:

```
  Symbol `printf' causes overflow in R_X86_64_PC32 relocation
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

this is How i compile:

```
   gcc mod.s -l:libc.so -o mod
```

when I replace libc.so with libc.a, It still shows Sementation fault

```
 .file  "mod.c"
.text
.section    .rodata
.LC0: 
   .string  "%d"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    $16, %rsp
movl    $3, -8(%rbp)
movl    $2, -4(%rbp)
movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
cltd
idivl   -4(%rbp)
movl    %edx, -4(%rbp)
movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, %esi
leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
movl    $0, %eax
leave
ret
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 7.4.0"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

When I add @PLT after printf it goes right, But I just want to use -l in gcc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `-llibc`, gcc already links that by default.

The problem here is that modern GCC defaults to making a PIE executable (position-independent), which is an ELF "shared object".  The linker treats it more like a library and doesn't automatically create PLT stubs for calls to undefined symbol names.  (I don't think this behaviour is necessary, `ld` *could* let you do this.)

**The easy solution here is `gcc -no-pie -fno-pie -o mod mod.s`**

Then you can write `call printf` and it Just Works.

With that command line, you'll create a dynamically-linked ELF executable.  The  linker rewrites your `call printf` to `call printf@plt` for you (disassemble it and see, with `objdump -drwC` to print relocations.).  The offset between the libc load address and your code's address is not a link-time constant.  (And could be larger than 2^32 anyway).

If you use `-static`, the `call printf` resolves to the actual address of the `printf` definition copied into your executable from `libc.a`.

---

I'm guessing that the option of building a static or dynamic executable from the same source is why `ld` is willing to rewrite calls to PLT stubs for ELF executables but not ELF shared objects (like PIE executables).

See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) for more about PIE.

The other way to call shared library functions is `call *printf@GOTPCREL(%rip)`, like gcc does if you compile with `-fno-plt`.  This bypasses the PLT entirely, just doing a call through the function pointer in the GOT (which you access with a RIP-relative addressing mode).

The NASM version of this is `call [rel printf wrt ..got]`
as an alternative to `call printf wrt ..plt`.  [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code)