# Calling a simple assembly program from gcc

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I have the following program to print a number via the `printf` function:

```
format: .ascii "Your number is: %d.\n\0"

.globl main
main:

    // printf('%d', 55);
    mov $format, %rdi
    mov $55, %rsi
    mov $0, %eax

    // call printf with 16-byte aligned stack:
    sub $8, %rsp
    call printf
    add $8, %rsp

    // return 0;
    mov $0, %eax
    ret
```

```
$ gcc -no-pie int.s -o int; ./int
Your number is: 55.
```

I have a few questions about this as I was writing this:

- Does the `sub $8...add $8` work fine to preserve alignment? For example, the same as doing `push %rbp...pop %rbp`.
- I tried adding in some `.data` and `.rodata` and `.text` directives/sections but each time I would get a warning/error. Why aren't those allowed when invoking an assembly program via `gcc`? How, for example, does C know that "format" is `.data` and "main" is in `.text` ?
- Is `mov $0, %eax; ret` the proper way to exit the `C` main function from assembly?
- Finally, what modifications would I need to make this program run without doing `-no-pie` ?

Comment: What warnings did you get?  I don't get any.  Note though that there isn't any such directive as `.rodata`; you must write `.section .rodata`.

Comment: @NateEldredge actually you'r right. The warnings go away when I do `-no-pie`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the `sub $8...add $8` work fine to preserve alignment? For example, the same as doing `push %rbp...pop %rbp`.

Yes.  If you read the instruction description of `push` and `pop` you'll see that they have the same effect on the stack pointer, besides reading/writing to the register and stack memory which you don't care about.  However `push` and `pop` are shorter instructions.

> How, for example, does C know that "format" is `.data` and "main" is in `.text` ?

Unless you tell it, it doesn't, and they aren't.  If you dump your executable with `objdump --full-contents` you will see that your string has been put in `.text` along with everything else, since you never told the assembler to do otherwise.

> Is `mov $0, %eax; ret` the proper way to exit the `C` main function from assembly?

Yes, though `xor %eax, %eax ; ret` is more efficient.  [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295)

> Finally, what modifications would I need to make this program run without doing `-no-pie` ?

You're not allowed to use absolute addresses as immediates in a position-independent executable, so `mov $format, %rdi` is no good.  Instead use RIP-relative addressing: `lea format(%rip), %rdi`.  Everything else is fine.

Comment: thanks again for this great answer. You mention that doing `ret` is fine in this question but in the previous comment you mentioned not to use `ret` to exit from C's main. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @carl.hiass: I was confused about the context in the previous comment.  You can `ret` from `main`, but not from `_start`.

Comment: I get something similar to this when removing the `no-pie`, even with changing the `lea format`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071280/nasm-symbol-printf-causes-overflow-in-r-x86-64-pc32-relocation. In `gdb` it's the `call printf` statement that says invalid memory address.

Comment: @carl.hiass: Show **your** code, please.  It worked for me.

Comment: sure, updated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66809271/removing-the-need-for-no-pie-in-an-assembly-program.

Comment: *You're not allowed to use absolute addresses as immediates in a position-independent executable* - You can't use *32-bit* immediates, but Linux does actually allow text relocations / fixups in a PIE or shared lib so `movabs $symbol, %rdi` will link and run in a PIE executable.  It's obviously worse than `lea symbol(%rip), %rdi`, but the real reason `mov $foo, %rdi` doesn't work is that it assembles as `mov $sign_extended_imm32, %rdi` with an R_X86_64_32S relocation, not R_X86_64_64.  [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)

Comment: (And [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)).  Even more fun, `mov rdi, symbol` works in NASM code (but not YASM), because of their choices for what size to assume for an unknown symbol address.  Oh, current `ld` warns about creating a DT_TEXTREL in a PIE; that's good.

Comment: I thought I remembered needing to write `call printf@plt`  (or `call *printf@GOTPCREL(%rip)`) for code to link into a PIE.  But apparently `ld` will create PLT stubs if needed when linking a PIE now; I'm pretty sure it didn't used to.  Yeah, [How can I call printf normally in assembly without @PLT but just call printf with -l option in gcc with standard library,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56404855) confirms that older systems used to try to link `call printf` directly, without a PLT stub, leading to overflow of the text relocation when libc isn't loaded within 2GiB (which it won't be).