# Removing the need for -no-pie in an assembly program

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, x86-64

I have the following program to print a number in assembly:

```
.section .rodata
format: .ascii "Your number is: %d.\n\0"
.section .text
.globl main
main:
    lea format(%rip), %rdi
    mov $55, %rsi
    mov $0, %eax
    sub $8, %rsp
    call printf
    add $8, %rsp
    mov $0, %eax
    ret
```

And it works fine when being compiled via gcc on ubuntu with `-no-pie`:

```
ubuntu$ gcc -no-pie int.s -o int; ./int
Your number is: 55.
```

However, when I remove `-no-pie` it jumps to the wrong address for the `printf` statement. Single-stepping in `gdb` shows that when it does the `call printf` instruction it returns something along the lines of:

> Cannot access memory at address 0x5554f7a48f00

Or, running it directly from the command-line I get:

> $ gcc int.s -o int; ./int
> ./int: Symbol `printf' causes overflow in R_X86_64_PC32 relocation

Why does this occur, and how would I make the above program work without `-no-pie` in the command-line?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `call printf@plt`. It's strange you get a runtime error instead of compile time which I do.

Comment: @Jester yea, that works. Thank you. Want to post an answer showing what that does and what my error was without it?

Comment: We'll just wait for Peter to show up and find the duplicate LOL

Comment: @Jester here's a good one actually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5469334/12283181. The problem with duplicates is I don't know anything about `plt` before asking the question so I wouldn't know to look it up...that happens for a lot of dupes I'm guessing.

Comment: My gcc seems to link to `printf@plt` all by itself without needing to be told.  Maybe your version does not for some reason.

Comment: @Jester by implication, would all C-runtime functions called in assembly without `-no-pie` require the `@plt` suffix?

Comment: Not just C runtime, any shared library function.

Comment: @carl.hiass Generally speaking, you aren't doing anything wrong if you route calls to any external functions through the PLT.