# How to use ld to make a dynamic library?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, ld

I'm  trying to make a dynamic library with assembly code. So i convert my .asm files to .o with nasm (nasm -f elf64 filename.asm). And when i link them with ld (ld files.o -shared -o libasm.so -fPIC), it gives me an error `` ld: strstr.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `strlen' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
ld: final link failed: Bad value ``. Could someone can help me, how to compile them ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are the right commands, but you have to write position-independent code and that also doesn't try to reach libc symbols directly with a 32-bit relative offset.  Instead you have to call library functions via the PLT.  Just like for a PIE executable.  See [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52126328)

Comment: Try to call `strlen` as `strlen wrt ..plt` to fix this issue.