# Problem with linking an object file with the standard library

Tags: assembly, gcc, linker, x86-64, position-independent-code

Well, I use `nasm` to produce `test.o` from my `test.s`. When I then run `gcc test.o`, it gives me the error message

/usr/bin/ld: test.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
test.s:
    global main
    extern puts

    section .text
main:
    mov rdi, message
    call    puts
    ret
message:
    db  "Hello World", 0
```

What this error message means and how to fix it?

Also, in this case i use `gcc` to link my *object* file with the standard library, but how can i use `ld` to do the same job?

I am running **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**

Comment: Use `call puts wrt ..plt`

Comment: Alternatively, link with `-no-pie`.

Comment: Wow, it actually works... But what this bunch of words after `call` means? Why I found on the internet a lot of `asm` code snippets and used toolchains like `nasm -felf64 test.s && gcc test.o && ./a.out`, but in my case that didn't work?

Comment: My answer on the linked duplicate [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131094) explains what this does.  The tutorials you're finding were written before `-pie` was the default for gcc.  See also [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) which will also be a potential problem if you're following tutorials written for non-PIE linking.

Comment: Ok, thx you all!!