# Error: undefined reference to `scanf' when linking NASM ELF relocatable using 'ld'

Tags: assembly, nasm, ld, elf

I have a NASM assembly file that I have compiled using the command:
`nasm -felf64 -g -Fdwarf groundFloor.asm -o file.o` where `groundFloor.asm` is my NASM file. Using `ld file.o -o file` gives me a `undefined reference to 'scanf'` error. Does anyone know how to fix this so that it results in a ELF executable?

Comment: Please show us your code.  It is likely that you'll have to link with the libc.  Likely, addition changes are needed to guarantee a working binary.

Comment: Simple fix is to use `main` as entry point and use `gcc` for linking.

Comment: You didn't tell `ld` to link with libc, so it didn't.  Like Jester says, if you're going to call libc functions, linking with `gcc` is normally better; writing a `main` instead of `_start` is the simple way.  See also [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52126328)