# Cannot compile asm x86_64 when trying to use malloc

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64

I'm new to assembly so I'm not really sure about what I'm doing. I hope you can help me and point out all my errors, thank you in advance.
I was trying to recreate the [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) function in asm and in all the tests I did it seems to work.
This is my code:

```
extern __errno_location

section .note.GNU-stack

section .text
    global ft_read

ft_read:
    mov rax, 0
    ; rdi already set
    ; rsi already set
    ; rdx already set
    syscall
    cmp rax, 0
    jl _syscallFail
    ret

_syscallFail:
    neg rax
    push rax
    call __errno_location
    pop qword [rax]
    mov rax, -1
    ret
```

If I compile with this command: `nasm -f elf64 ft_read.s && gcc -no-pie main.c ft_read.o` it works just fine.
But, if I try to remove the `-no-pie` gcc gives me an incomprehensible error, at least for me:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ft_read.o: warning: relocation against `__errno_location@@GLIBC_2.2.5' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: ft_read.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__errno_location@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I searched on the internet but I couldn't find anything helpful, probably because I don't really understand the problem here. Anyway, I tried to compile with this commands also, but they all failed like the one I've mentioned above.

- `gcc -lc main.c ft_read.o`
- `gcc -fPIE main.c ft_read.o`
- `gcc -lc -fPIE main.c ft_read.o`

I also tried to change the `extern __errno_location` into this, but got the same error:

```
section .data
    extern __errno_location
```

---

Here, some info about my machine:

- Ubuntu 23.10
- Linux 6.5.0-25-generic
- x86_64
- gcc 13.2.0
- NASM 2.16.01

Comment: Works fine here. That said, you might try to use `call __errno_location wrt ..plt` instead and see if that helps.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52126328) if `__errno_location` is like other library functions.  (Your question title mentions `malloc`, but I don't see that anywhere in the question body.)

Comment: The `recompile with -fPIE` part of the error message is only relevant if the object file was generated from C by a compiler.  For hand-written asm, *you* have to write PIE-compatible asm.  Also, `errno` has type `int`.  A qword `pop` will overwrite the following 4 bytes.  `pop rcx` / `mov [rax], ecx`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question title. Anyway, I solved it using `call __errno_location wrt ..plt` like @Jester said. Now I guess I'm going to try understand what that `wrt ..plt` means and does. Thank you all, you really helped me out.